# Active admin- scope and filter not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I am using active-admin(AA, 1.0.0) in a rails 4.2 app. I am displaying a list of online users. I want to add 'scope' such that the links for different type of users with their counts are displayed above the main list.

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  menu parent: "Users", label: "Online Users", url: '/ admin/users/online_users'                                                                                

  collection_action :online_users, method: :get do
    @users = User.select{|i| i.online?}
  end

  belongs_to :organization, optional: true
  scope :all, default: true
  scope :admins do |users| users.with_role(:admin) end
  scope :type1 do |users| users.with_role(:type1) end
  scope :type2 do |users| users.with_role(:type2) end
end
```

The list gets displayed but the scopes aren't. What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean with `the scopes aren't`? Do you miss the scope switcher oder do you get a empty list? Pleas post the source of `with_role`

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use  `collection_action` as a redirect; you should use `scoped_collection` or a filter for this. Your scopes look ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use a `collection_action` to get the sub-collection you want, you should use `scoped_collection` to limit your attention to online users. This way, everything else works exactly as it should.

Ideally, your `users` table will have an `online` boolean column, in which case adding a simple `where` clause will do the trick. If it doesn't, i.e. `online?` is a computed method that can't be queried, then you'll need to compute the set of online user `id`s first. That won't scale well, so watch out.

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  menu parent: "Users", label: "Online Users", url: '/admin/users/online_users'

  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      # if online is a boolean column (best performance):
      super.where(online: true)

      # if online is a computed method (convert to ActiveRecord::Relation):
      # ids = User.all.select(&:online?).map(&:id)
      # super.where(id: ids)
    end
  end

  belongs_to :organization, optional: true

  scope :all, default: true
  scope :admins, -> (u) { u.with_role(:admin) }
  scope :type1, -> (u) { u.with_role(:type1) }
  scope :type2, -> (u) { u.with_role(:type2) }
end
```

You could also achieve this using a filter on your ordinary `users` admin route (assuming you have one).